# alternative for .attr() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this).attr('id':'name', visibility:'hidden', fill:'black', stroke-width:2)
```

used this approach for 1000  element to set their attribute. All working fine, but .attr() takes 10ms to execute, I need to optimize it, is there any alternative for .attr().

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you need such performance  , use pure js instead.

Comment: That doesn't look live valid syntax.

Comment: Caching `$(this)` to a variable would save a lot of msecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than changing attributes directly, why not add a class to those elements that is defined to have the attributes you want?

I ran a performance test here: http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-classsname
And the attr() method was 33% slower on my browser/OS.

Here's how:

javascript:

```
this.className = "custom-class";
this.id = 'name';
```

accompanying css:

```
.custom-class {
  visiblity: hidden;
  fill: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

Also, you're missing the brackets in your attr() call, and the hyphenated stroke-width method needs to be put in quotes, like this:

```
$(this).attr({id:'name', visibility:'hidden', fill:'black', 'stroke-width':2});
```

Answer (score 3):

try something like this,For better performance use setAttribute().

The setAttribute() method adds the specified attribute, and gives it the specified value.

```
this.setAttribute("id","name");
this.style.visibility =  'hidden';
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest alternative would be to set the corresponding property of an attribute directly.

```
this.id = 'name';
this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-vs-setattribute/2